# How can i display list vertically after doing float:right. How can I display the list vertically after float:right

Tags: html, css

```
.container{
         float:right;
         }
```

How can I display list after statement float:right. I want the list on right side vertically

Comment: please, provide more code and information to understand the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have bunch of element and all are given position right then give them clear**

For more reference https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/

```
    .container{
      float:right;
      clear: both;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try and use

```
.container
{
         float:right;
         display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think You want like this.  Right Side **Vertical List**

**Check the Snippets is below.**

```css
.container
 {
    width: auto;
    float:right;
    background: #a2e3e3;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
  }
.container ul{padding:0px; margin:0px}
.container ul li{list-style-type:disc;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>List 1</li>
      <li>List 2</li>
      <li>List 3</li>
      <li>List 4</li>
      <li>List 5</li>
      <li>List 6</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well from what i understand the user asked that he wants a list to display on the right side after the float right element.

One way of doign it is : First of all you should understand that float:right will take that div out of the DOM flow and float it right. So for the next element you have to clear:both; and then text-align: right; And whatever you put in the text aligned right element it will appear on the right side.